# .text() not extracting name?

Tags: jquery, html

### What is happening

[image]

### What I want

When I click on the `.icon-pencil-circle` of the `.student-box` I want to copy the name in `.student-name` and put it in the `.student-name` of `#popup-rename`.

Except when I do this, all that appears in the `#popup-rename .student-name` is a blank box. For some reason, nothing is copying.

I can't figure out if I'm selecting the wrong object when I'm copying the name into `selectedStudentName` *or* if `.text()` is not working.

If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated!

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="student-table">
        <div class="student-row">
            <div class="student-box">
                <div class="student-name">
                    <h1>Alyssa</h1> 
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
...
<div id="popup-rename" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            ...
            <div class="content">
                <div class="student-name student-rect">
                    <h1>Student Name</h1>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selectedStudentName = "Student Name";
    $('.student-box').on('click','.icon-pencil-circle',function(){
        selectedStudentName = $(this).closest('.student-name').text();
        $('#popup-rename').find('.student-name').text(selectedStudentName);
    });
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/eyrvos89/)

Comment: closest function is not working as you expect because this function look for the first ancestor, check this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp

Comment: $(".student-name > h1").text() instead of $(this).closest(..).text() will get you what you want

Comment: so, uhm... your code targets some circle icon, but said dom node isn't in your sample code. how are we supposed to help?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the $(this).closest(); selector. I would be more specific with your selecting. I got it to work with .parentsUntil(). The following will grab the .student-box (one parent short of .student-row) and then .find the  tag to get the text content. Also, your JS Fiddle doesn't have jQuery included so make sure you select that in the Javascript settings if you're testing in there.

```
selectedStudentName = $(this).parentsUntil('.student-row').find('.student-name h1').text();
```